# Error when trying to get console output of scheduled:summary command

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the output of the command scheduled:summary function of laravel 5 and echo it in the browser, what i am currently doing is the following

```
public function scheduledCommands()
    {
      $output = new BufferedOutput;
      Artisan::call('scheduled:summary',array(),$output);   
      return $output->fetch();
   }
```

When i call this function i get this following error : 
Use of undefined constant STDOUT - assumed 'STDOUT'

This method works for any other command just fine but this one, also when i execute it from CLI everything works fine and i get a table like this with my scheduled commands:

[image: scheduled:summary executed from CLI]

I don't understand what is different with this command, any further on why i get this error will be appreciated.

Comment: This makes sense. PHP does not define `STDOUT` when used as an Interpreter through Apache, it only defines `STDOUT` when executed through the CLI, and not all Artisan commands make use of the `STDOUT`.  Can you try adding `define(STDOUT, 'php://stdout');` and see if that resolves it?

Comment: Yes but it worked that way for all other commands, i tried to add the line of code that you gave me but i got another error Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of ParseError given

Comment: That command is from the [`Indatus/dispatcher`](https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher) package. According to the github issue tracker, [this issue](https://github.com/Indatus/dispatcher/issues/42) was supposed to be fixed in 1.3.1. What version of the package are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.4 version the latest one on their github

Comment: Are you sure? The table headers in your screen shot look like they're from <= 1.1.3. What does your composer.json look like?

Comment: The screenshot is not mine just to show how the output looks like... here is my composer.json require section : "type": "project",
 "require": {
  "laravel/framework": "4.2.*", 
  "fzaninotto/faker": "1.3.*@dev",
  "folklore/image": "0.1.*",
  "indatus/dispatcher": "1.4.*@dev",
  "unikent/curl": "dev-master"
 },